# How can I sacrifice a bit of DC Voltage to transform it to DC current?

Tags: voltage, transistors, current, current-measurement, electronic-load

I made a project with using voltage doubler(which has input of 12V) which output is 43V(I expected 24V) but current is low when connecting the 150 ohm resistor,its about 150mA,but I dont need so much voltage so I need to transform it to current which need to be about 500-1000mA,how can it be done,I heard that you can amplify current with base biased NPN transistor.

Here is the schematic diagram:

[image]

I will replace both pots with LM317 and remove R5.

Comment: Why use a voltage doubler if you don't need the voltage? On the other hand, if you want to drive a 150 ohm resistor with 1000 ma, you will need 150 volts, not to mention that the resistor will have to dissipate 150 watts. You need to explain what you are trying to do so that we can come up with a suitable solution.

Comment: @Barry I got 43V output from 12V input on the voltage doubler,I expected the output to be about 24V,but instead I got 43V which is a much more than I expected.

Comment: @Barry I need to make a simple DC power supply.

Comment: A circuit diagram would be helpful.  What is your 12V source...dc or ac?

Comment: @AlmostDone Its a transformer with input of 230V and output of 12V rms its rating is 3.2VA

Comment: Not that it changes the answer, but "amplify" is the wrong word to use here. An _[amplifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amplifier)_ is a circuit that adds _power_ to a signal. That is, it has a power input, and a signal input, and an output where a more powerful version of the input signal appears. The circuit that you are trying to build looks like some kind of a _[power supply](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_supply)_.

Comment: @jameslarge Yes,its meant to be power supply,but I will exchange amplify to transform

Comment: @jameslarge Mainly some electric motors but still I wanted to test out some more complex circuits like 555 timer piano.

Comment: @KukiMuki (1) Reverse voltage on the LED -- not so good. (2) You will not realistically get anywhere near .1 A, let alone more than that, with a voltage doubler using those tiny caps. Try 2.2-10 mF and see what happens.

Comment: 24V at 500mA is 12VA. Your transformer is rated at 3.2VA - this should tell you something.

Comment: @jonk Oh,those are caps default value,I am using much bigger ones which are 470uF

Comment: @KukiMuki Well, those are okay if you like lots of ripple voltage under the load of \$150\:\Omega\$. Would be nice if you'd get details right on a schematic to avoid a misunderstanding or two.

Answer (score 1):

You have a basic misconception, throw away the doubler and simply use a full-bridge rectifier.

12Vrms is ~33Vpp. An ideal voltage doubler with no losses or load would turn this into ~66Vdc.

All you need is to rectify the 33Vpp and you would get what you want. Assuming that the transformer and the rest of the elements can sustain your 1A, of course.

But that’s essentially what you have actually built, albeit less efficiently. The reason you are getting 48Vdc is because the low load in the transformer is providing more than 12Vrms.

Answer (score 0):

The NPN transistor can amplify the current of one signal to another signal but that current still has to come from some power supply.

For the current levels that you are talking about what you need is a switching power supply converter module. You will need a source power supply to drive the converter module and the adjust the output voltage to the level that you want. The converter will have to be rated at a current output capability of at least 1A to support what you want to do.

Also keep in mind that there is no magic to be had. The power from the source power supply will always be greater than the power delivered to your load. Power being in Watts = Voltage * Current.

Since you specified that you were using a voltage doubler now one has to surmise that you were starting with something like a 24V supply. If you need a voltage at the output above this like 36 or 40V then you need to look for a boost (step up) converter. If in reality you have an output voltage requirement that is less than the input voltage then you want to look for a buck (step down) converter.

Rather than build a converter you may want to look online (amazon, ebay etc) for ready-made converter modules. Many are available at reasonable cost.

Comment: I used doubler from transformer which output is 13V,I expected 24V output,but I got 43V output.